# jQuery retrieve a value from a <ul> list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the  following script that creates a list of names :

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>cashier/walkin_patient_payments",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(payment_list) {
            pat_payment_list = $('#walkin_patient_payment').empty();
            if (payment_list === null) {

            } else {
                $.each(payment_list, function(i, payment_list) {
                    pat_payment_list.append('<li><a href="#walkin_patient_form" id="walkin_payment_link" class="walkin_payment_link"><i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-user"> </i>' + payment_list.walkin_patient_name + '</a><span style="color:red !important;"> Kshs : ' + payment_list.amount + '</span>\n\
          <input type="hidden" id="walkin_id_list" name="walkin_id_list" class="walkin_id_list" value="' + payment_list.walkin_id + '"/>\n\
    </br></li>');
                });
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            //error do something
        }
    });
}, 3000);
```

Which is appended to the following UL list :

```
<ul class = "dashboard-list walkin_patient_payment" id="walkin_patient_payment">
</ul>
```

But when I try to run the  following script that is supposed to pick individual walkin id from the list it only gives the  value of the  first list even when I click the  number 5th list.

Below is the script :

```
$('.walkin_patient_payment').on('click', '.walkin_payment_link', function() {
    //get
    var walkin_id = $(this).closest('ul').find('input[name="walkin_id_list"]').val();
    alert(walkin_id);
});
```

What is the  best way to implement this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first problem is that in your append, you create multiple elements with the same id (walkin_payment_link), which is bad. Then I dont understand why you use .closest('ul') to find your input. You just need $(this).find(). remove the closest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are traversing to ul element and `.find('input[name="walkin_id_list"]')` will return all the inputs with name `walkin_id_list` in ul. and using `.val()` on collection of elements will only return the value of first element.

You need to use `.closest('li')` instead of `.closest('ul')`:

```
 var walkin_id = $(this).closest('li').find('input[name="walkin_id_list"]').val();
```

Also note that you are generating the elements with same ids. IDs should always be unique. You can rather use same class instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement click directly on li

```
$('.walkin_patient_payment li').click(function () {

            var walkin_id = $(this).find('input[name="walkin_id_list"]').val();
            alert(walkin_id);
});
```